# getting error when importing to phpmyadmin from mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

i was working in mysql workbench to export my database dump file to upload it to my phpmyadmin database , but i get empaty database , second i'm showing this error :

## 1044 - Access denied for user 'hesham'@'mocha6004.mochahost.com' to database 'sams'

and my database account have all premisson

my database file code :

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `sams` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `sams`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.11, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: sams
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.13-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
--
-- Table structure for table `class`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `class`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `CLASS_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CLASS_NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `GRAdE_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `STAGE_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `school_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CLASS_ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `class`
    --

    LOCK TABLES `class` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `class` (`CLASS_ID`, `CLASS_NAME`, `GRAdE_ID`, `STAGE_ID`,     `school_id`) VALUES     (1,'1-10','1','1',1),(3,'2-20','1','1',1);
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as *phpmyadmin database*. phpMyAdmin is a MySql client software as it is MySql Workbench. So where are you importing your dump?

Comment: In my webhost account i have phpmyadmin and i wanna to import database to it but give me the above error .

Comment: **Create your database first**. Then grant all necessary permissions for your user to that database. And only then execute this dump.

Comment: i have done that but still have error when importing to it : 1044 - Access denied for user 'hesham'@'mocha6004.mochahost.com' to database 'sams'

Comment: You either have rights or you don't. The error says that you don't. Therefore it suggests that you didn't grant all necessary rights for your user.

Comment: Note that the username, password and host are verified in the access privilege system. Often, one forgets to verify also from which host the request comes.